# How to align textview in the center of toolbar while adding backbutton in support actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have created custom toolbar as action bar of my activity. I want the title label to be displayed in center of my toolbar.

Toolbar Layout resource file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_select"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="sample text"
                android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Heading"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="second line heading"
                android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And my Activity contains,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar_select_seat);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

I wanted to align all three `TextView` in center of my toolbar, but could not be able to align in exact center of my toolbar. When I run the application in my device it's not aligned correctly. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) docs:

> One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

So you want `center_horizontal` on the view that will be in the Toolbar, in this case the LinearLayout. You can make it `wrap_content` so it will be centered in the toolbar only taking the room it needs. Then you set its `gravity` to `center_horizontal` so its contents are centered within it. You can then remove all the `gravity_` attributes on all the children as they are now aligned based on the `LinearLayout`. I tweaked your sample:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_select"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/cmn_add" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="sample text"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="Heading"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="second line heading"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

That gives me something like this:

[image: Layout Preview]

Hope that helps!

P.S. - When posting issues about layout not looking correct, it would be very useful to post a screenshot of the layout you're getting and a mock or something of what you actually want. Otherwise people have to guess based on your description.